# How do I find elements by XPath in selenium with multiple classes?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I want to scrape the titles of all jobs from an Upwork job search which are stored in a  tag like this:

```
<h4 data-job-title="::$ctrl.job" class="job-title m-xs-top-bottom p-sm-right ng-isolate-scope">
<a data-ng-bindhtml="jsuJobTitleController.job.title|truncateHtmlByWords:jsuJobTitleController.getWordsThreshold()" data-ng-click="jsuJobTitleController.onJobTitleClick($event)" data-ng-href="/jobs/Email-Analytics-Custom_~0150c1eb58019b8306/" class="job-title-link break visited ng-binding" data-ng-class="{'text-muted': jsuJobTitleController.isHidden}" data-itemprop="url" href="/jobs/Email-Analytics-Custom_~0150c1eb58019b8306/">
Email Analytics Custom
</a> 
</h4>
```

I have tried using one of the possible classes:

```
jobs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h4[@class="job-title"]')
```

And all the classes:

```
jobs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h4[contains(@class, 'job-title') and contains(@class, 'm-xs-top-bottom') and contains(@class, 'p-sm-right') and contains(@class, 'ng-isolate-scope')]")
```

but both methods just return empty lists - which is weird as this indicates that it is matching something? Since I would expect an error if it couldn't match an element.

Could anyone advice how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are trying to match elements having exactly 1 class name `job-title` while there are more class names there, so you should use `contains` there. Like this:

```
jobs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h4[contains(@class,"job-title")]')
```

also possibly you have to add a wait / delay before that to let the page be loaded.
But first you have to use correct locators

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:-

```
jobTitles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//h4[contains(@class,'job-title')]/a")
for e in jobTitles:
    e.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below xpath :

```
//a[contains(@href, '/jobs/Email-Analytics-Custom')]
```

I would suggest to have Explicit wait

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/jobs/Email-Analytics-Custom')]")))
element.click()
```

If you would like to scrape all the titles instead :

then use the below xpath :

```
//h4[@data-job-title]
```

use `find_elements` to store all `elements` in a **list**.

```
for title in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h4[@data-job-title]")
    print(title.text)
```